# Regular functions and induced topologies.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

I just started reading on algebraic geometry, can someone explain the topology going on in the background here. I have two question that I would appreciate if someone can answer.

1. In (i), $Y$ is an open subset, indeed its a quasi affine variety. As we consider an open subset $U \subset Y$, do we consider it as an open subset of the induced topology on $Y$ or as an open subset of the topology on $\mathbb{A}^n$ ?
2. In (iii) I think the same type of question arise for me, the $k$-algebra of regular functions on $U$ is considered under which topology? Indeed for every point $P \in U$ we need to find an open subset $U' \subset U$ containing $P$ such that the regular function is locally the quotient of polynomials. But which topology are we using on $U$ and on $U'$?

I have a feeling that all the open subsets considered here should just be thought of as open subsets in the ambient space $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have left out some important information here - $Y$ is an open subset of a closed subset of $\Bbb A^n$, so open sets $U\subset Y$ may not actually be open in $\Bbb A^n$. For an example, let $Y=\{(x,0)\mid x\neq 0\} \subset \Bbb A^2$ and $U\subset Y = \{(x,0)\mid x\neq 0,1\}$. Then $U$ is not open in $\Bbb A^2$, but it is the intersection of an open set $\{(x,y)\mid x\neq 1\}\subset \Bbb A^2$ with $Y$. An open set in $Y$ is always the intersection of an open set in $\Bbb A^n$ with $Y$, though, by the definition of the induced topology. So in each case ($Y$, $U$, $U'$) we are talking about the induced topology.

Comment: Thanks for a really clear answer. 

On a side note, I had the same confusion with quasi projective varieties. Its defined as an open subset of a closed irreducible subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$. I suppose the same yields here, "open subset" considering the induced topology, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${}{}$

Comment: thanks. If you dont mind, why is $U$ not open in $\mathbb{A}^2$?

Comment: There are lots of ways to see this, but one quick one is that it's contained in the closed set $V(y)$, whereas no nonempty open set in $\Bbb A^2$ is contained in any proper closed subset.

Comment: hmm im trying to figure out why. If $C$ is a nonempty open set in $\mathbb{A}^2$ such that it is contained in a proper closed subset $C'$, does this somehow contradict that $C'$ is closed? I.e that would be $\mathbb{A}^2 - C'$ is closed..?

Comment: $\Bbb A^2$ is irreducible, so if $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are closed subsets so that $Z_1\cup Z_2=\Bbb A^2$, we must have either $Z_1=\Bbb A^2$ or $Z_2=\Bbb A^2$. To apply this in our situation, if we have a nonempty open set $U$ contained in a closed subset $C$, then by taking $Z_1=U^c$ and $Z_2=C$ plus noting that $Z_1\neq \Bbb A^2$ as $U$ is nonempty we see that $C$ must be $\Bbb A^2$.

Comment: very clear, thanks, I wish I could upvote you again.